# Why is it common to use select new in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

When I look for examples of LINQ statements, often the select result doesn't just return the object or properties directly but as a new anonymous type.
Why is this?

eg

```
var teenStudents = from s in studentList
where s.age > 12 && s.age < 20
select new { s };
```

why not just `select s;`

Comment: This is not the best example and also not something I see occur "often". In this case `select s` is far more common. That's the problem with your question. "Often" is opinion-based and specific cases may have specific reasons for using either form.

Comment: If you want to do a projection that includes multiple properties (say the equivalent of a SQL `SELECT Name, Age FROM Students`, then you need to select the appropriate properties into an anonymously typed object like `select new { s.Name, s.Age }`. I don't think I'd ever use `select { s }`, just `select s`

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the use case.

If the entire entity data is required, no further projection is required.

```
var teenStudents = from s in studentList
where s.age > 12 && s.age < 20
select s;
```

Some scenarios where we project the data into a new anonymous object is

- When we need to select only specific properties from say a large entity having 20 columns. It makes the querying efficient
- When we do not have an entity object to project the output to and you don't intend to create one

It could be something like

```
var teenStudents = from s in studentList
where s.age > 12 && s.age < 20
select new {Name= s.name, Age = s.age } ;
```

If you have another DTO class which you can project to, you can do

```
var teenStudents = from s in studentList
where s.age > 12 && s.age < 20
select new StudentDTO {Name= s.name, Age = s.age } ;
```